# javascript submit not submitting

Tags: javascript, submit

I have the following in my head:

```
<SCRIPT>
function submitFunction(i) {
   if (i==1) {
    alert('1');
    document.sales_order_details.action="/sales/_order";
    document.sales_order_details.submit()
    } 
    if (i==2) {
      alert('2');
      document.sales_order_details.action="/sales/delete_order";
      document.sales_order_details.submit()
    }
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

and the following in my body:

```
<form id="sales_order_details" action="/sales/delete_order" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Edit Order" onClick="submitFunction(1)">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Delete Order" onClick="submitFunction(2)">
</form>
```

The alert for '2' or '1' shows correctly but the form does not submit.

any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `<form id=` to `<form name=`, else you have to use document.getElementById()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your javascript function instead:

```
function submitFunction(i) {
    var form = document.getElementById('sales_order_details');

    if (i == 1)
        form.action = "/sales/_order";
    else if (i == 2)
        form.action = "/sales/delete_order";

    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have accessed the java script object hierarchy wrongly. after `document` you should access `form` to get your code work see the following: And you should use `name` attribute in `form` tag to work this code.

```
<SCRIPT>
function submitFunction(i) {
   if (i==1) {
    alert('1');
    document.form.sales_order_details.action="/sales/_order";
    document.form.sales_order_details.submit()
    } 
    if (i==2) {
      alert('2');
      document.form.sales_order_details.action="/sales/delete_order";
      document.form.sales_order_details.submit()
    }
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

the html form:

```
<form name="sales_order_details" action="/sales/delete_order" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Edit Order" onClick="submitFunction(1)">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Delete Order" onClick="submitFunction(2)">
</form>
```

Or:

you could use the form index number to access the form object in javascript. like `document.form[0].action`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.sales_order_details.submit()
```

to

```
document.forms['sales_order_details'].submit();
```

and your form will submit correctly.